# JavaScript Setting up a JSON array for later use

Tags: javascript, json

I am wanting to create a JSON array, create the fields and populate with data later on in my code. I am just wondering what the syntax is to go about this. I have tried so far but have a few parse errors;

```
<script>


var myJSONArray = [

{item: , cost: , quantity: }; // To set up the array ready for population
]
```

then later on ....

```
myJSONArray.push(milk,1.99,2); // then insert varying items into the array fields
```

Comment: Don't put semicolons in the middle of your array initialization literals.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see what you're trying to do but it isn't possible in JavaScript. You'll want to first initialize an empty array and then push the full objects to it as you build them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to create a JSON array (you are currently using a JavaScript array that contains a JavaScript object), you can use the `JSON.stringify` method.

Using Andy's code :

```
var arr = [];

arr.push({
  item: 'milk',
  cost: 1.99,
  quantity: 2
});

// Prints the JavaScript Array as a JSON array :
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

The [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function will return a String of a JavaScript value in the JSON format. You can then parse it with another language or store it into a new .json file. If that was you purpose.

**UPDATE** : The output of the previous code :

```
'[{"item":"milk","cost":1.99,"quantity":2}]'
```

Answer (score 6):

First, it's a *JavaScript* array.

Initialise your array then add objects to it:

```
var arr = [];

arr.push({
  item: 'milk',
  cost: 1.99,
  quantity: 2
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function within an object that will let you overwrite the item object.

```
<script>

var myJSONArray = {
    addItem: function(itemName, cost, quantity) {
        this.item = {"name": itemName, "cost": cost, "quantity": quantity}
        return true;
    },
    item: {name: "", cost: 0, quantity: 0}
}

// Usage:
myJSONArray.addItem("Milk", 3.00, 1);
console.log(myJSONArray.item); // returns {name: "Milk", cost: 3.00, quantity: 1}

</script>
```